# Dr.Racket, cons: expect 2 argument, but found 3

Tags: functional-programming, racket

I have this function along with some other functions, but when I run it, dr.racket says:

> cons: expect 2 argument, but found 3

I can't figure out where I got the `cons` incorrect, can someone help me?

```
;; Component -> ListOfCode
;; produce a list of codes of all parts required to build the given component
;; if a part appears twice, the code of the bar should also appear twice

(check-expect (list-code C0) (cons "000000" (cons "111000" (cons "222000" empty))))
(check-expect (list-code C1) (cons "000000" (cons "111000" (cons "111000" (cons 444000 empty)))))
(check-expect (list-code C3) (cons "000000" (cons "111000" (cons "555000" (cons "666000" (cons "666000" (cons "000000" (cons "111000" (cons "222000" (cons "000000" (cons "111000" (cons "111000" (cons 444000 empty)))))))))))))

;(define (list-code c) loc)
(define (list-code c)
  (cons (find-codes-loc (component-loc c))    ;fn-for-loc
        (get-code-lop (component-lop c))  ;fn-for-lop
        empty))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
(define (list-code c)
  (cons (find-codes-loc (component-loc c))  -- argument 1
        (get-code-lop (component-lop c))    -- argument 2
        empty))                             -- argument 3
```